# How to I convert postgres SQL to SQLite for the to_jsonb postgres function?

Tags: json, sqlite

I am moving my database from `postgres` to `sqlite`.

I have this postgres SQL statement

```sql
select 
    s.id,
    (
        select to_jsonb(alb)
        from (
            select 
                sum(case when "statusId" = 'passed' then 1 else 0 end) as "passed",
                sum(case when "statusId" = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) as "failed"
            from "Script"
            where "suiteId" = s.id
            GROUP BY s.id
        ) alb
    ) as "statuses"
from "Suite" as s
```

This gives me results in this format
[image]

How can I make an equivalent SQL statement in SQLite? And If SQLite does not have this functionality, then is there any work arounds?

**EDIT** 
based on @peak 's response, I have updated the query to the following:

```sql
select
    s.id,
    (
        select  json_object(alb)
        from (
            SELECT 
                sum(case when "statusId" = 'passed' then 1 else 0 end) as "passed",
                sum(case when "statusId" = 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) as "failed"

                from "Script"
                where "suiteId" = s.id
        ) alb
    )  states
from "Suite" s;
```

But i am getting the error: `Result: no such column: alb`
Does any one know how to use the json_object with the above query?

Comment: Look into the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension?

Comment: i did not know. Looking now.

Comment: @Shawn I am confused. JSON1 seems like it has to be compiled? Here is the situation. I am building an app that used SQLite DB. The app will sit on end-users MacOS computers. Is there a way to use JSON1 with sqlite so that these end-users will not have to compile it into their SQLite themselves (in order for my app to work)?

Comment: SQLite does not have a JSON datatype, so chances are your clients won't need the functionality provided by the JSON1 extension, even if JSON values are stored in the database.

Comment: If the version of sqlite you're using wasn't built with the extension enabled, then you'd have to compile it as a module and load it at runtime, yes. But it's easier (depending on language) just to include sqlite directly in your project with the appropriate options instead of relying on whatever random os provided library is lying around.

Comment: @Shawn I will try to get the below working first. Once i get the SQL working, then i'll move to making it compatible. I know you answered what i asked in the comments, but on reflection, the question i asked is different from the original above. I'll get to this part next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot or don't want to load the JSON1 extension, you could simply construct the JSON text, e.g. by:

```
select "{""passed"": " || 'passed' || ", ""failed"":" || 'failed' || "}"
```

Otherwise, you could use the `json_object` function, as described on the JSON1 page: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: json_object was what i needed